# How do you train LSTMs on time series data with too many time steps?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trainig LSTM/GRUs on time series data.

My input data's shape is (5000,12) i.e. 5000 time steps and at each time step has 12 dimensions.
When I am trying to run LSTM on this data taking each time step (dim: 12) at a time; this means I am unrolling LSTM 5000 times and I am unable to train the network on my laptop as it is exceeding 16gb ram.

One solution I can think of is can I combine, say, 10 time steps data and feed that data (dim: 10*12) to LSTM network (potentially unrolling only 500 times)...

Can this give me good results?

Answer (score 1):

there are various ways to tackle this problem depending on the dataset you have, have a look at this: http://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-long-sequences-long-short-term-memory-recurrent-neural-networks/